# Connecting mediastream to canvas

Tags: mediastream

I'm trying to read from a media stream source, make some webgl calls and then update a texture with the modified media stream. How can I connect a media stream to a canvas so that I can read/manipulate the image data? Repeatedly drawing from a video onto a canvas using drawImage is unacceptably slow on mobile.

Using chrome 56 I can captureStream() a video element, but I'm not sure how to route that to a canvas for manipulation. Any hints appreciated.